# Accordion with shared content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this accordion (javascript) that shows the content of the clicked button. But, what I want to do is to have the content aligning under the first row. I have a row with 7 buttons, and underneath I have 7 more and so on. 
Is there a way of making the content of every button aligning underneath the whole row? So if I press button 1, the content will align underneath the first row, and if I press button 9, the content will align under row 2 and so on.

code:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.row {
    color: grey;
    width: 13%;
    transition: 0.4s;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.panel {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button class="row"> 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>1 content</p>
</div>

<button class="row"> 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>2 content </p>

</div>

<button class="row"> 3</button>
<div class="panel">
   <p>3</p>

</div>
<button class="row"> 4</button>
<div class="panel">
   <p>4 content</p>

</div>
<button class="row"> 5</button>
<div class="panel">
   <p>5 content</p>

</div>
<button class="row"> 6</button>
<div class="panel">
   <p>6 content</p>

</div>
<button class="row"> 7</button>
<div class="panel">
   <p>7 content</p>

</div>
<button class="row"> 8</button>
<div class="panel">
   <p>8 content</p>

</div>
<button class="row"> 9</button>
<div class="panel">
   <p>9 content</p>

</div>
<button class="row"> 10</button>
<div class="panel">
   <p>10 content</p>

</div>
<button class="row"> 11</button>
<div class="panel">
   <p>11 content</p>

</div>
<button class="row"> 12</button>
<div class="panel">
   <p>12 content</p>

</div>
<button class="row"> 13</button>
<div class="panel">
   <p>13 content</p>

</div>
<button class="row"> 14</button>
<div class="panel">
   <p>14 content</p>

</div>
```

Comment: This is identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49006671/how-to-create-an-accordion-with-shared-content  Are you both doing the same student project or something? What have you tried so far? This isn't a free write-my-solution service, but we'll help you fix your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly advise to make use of css flex-box in such scenario.
Using flex-box you would simply have to first create a wrapper holding all rows (.column on the provided demo) then two rows (.verse on the provided demo) and then on top of that a division holding both button and its content. The whole structure would look in the following way:

```
<div class="column>
    <div class="verse">
        <div>
            /* your buttons and contents */
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working [demo](https://jsbin.com/rahohutoca/edit?html,css,js,output://) - I believe it explains the solution better than the above text.

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way where when I press number one, all the other accordions closes. So that there is only one accordion opened on all time

Comment: You could try attaching an 'active' class while opening an element and then when attempting to open another check whether there already is any with 'active' class opened. Take a look here https://jsbin.com/vugupemimi/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks but what I want is, when I press open 1, and then 2, number 1 closes directly. I dont know if im unclear

Comment: https://jsbin.com/vugupemimi/edit?html,css,js,console,output
Take a look now, hope that is what you had in mind!

Comment: but is there a way to make the content come from the right to left, instead from top to bottom?